# PHPRtfLite - RTF file opens as raw

Tags: php, yii, rtf

I am using PHPRtfLite library (http://sigma-scripts.de/phprtflite/docs/index.html) to produce an RTF file using PHP and Yii.

So far, I've made a simple "Hello world" function.

```
Yii::import('ext.phprtf.PHPRtfLite'); 
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('PHPRtfLite','registerAutoloader'), true); 
$rtf = new PHPRtfLite();

$sect = $rtf->addSection();
$sect->writeText('Hello world!', new PHPRtfLite_Font(), new PHPRtfLite_ParFormat());

//save rtf document
$rtf->sendRtf('takis.rtf');
```

File is created successfully, but when I open it (either wordpad or ms word) I do not see the actual content of the file but the raw code of the RTF:

```
{\rtf\ansi\deff0\fs20
{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\info
}
\paperw11907 \paperh16840 \deftab1298 \margl1701 \margr1701 \margt567 \margb1134 \pgnstart1\ftnnar \aftnnrlc \ftnstart1 \aftnstart1 
\pard \ql {\fs20 Hello world!}
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, in case someone is having the same issue in the coming future...

It seems to be a problem of the sendRTF function. Now, I save the created file locally:

```
$rtf->save('takis.rtf');
```

and then generate a link for the user to download the file. This works pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced same thing myself. I'm not sure, if you had same reasons, but in my case, there was extra newline in the beginning of PHP file, before `<?php` tag. When I used sendRtf to download file from browser, that newline ended up also in RTF file, making it invalid and as result, raw rtf code was displayed. When using save, such extra characters won't reach to file.

So one thing to check in similar situations - open Rtf file in Notepad and examine beginning of file.

Comment: This is the right answer. I have faced the similar issue in my application. There was an unwanted space before `<?php` in my code. I removed it and now the issue has been fixed. Thank you :)